# Cannot add Contour to layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, contour

I am brand new to QGIS as my uni has shut down but we still need to do our coursework they have asked up to make a bathymetry map on QGIS. It is a very simple map of sounding data we have taken and all I am trying to do is add a contour and a grid and I keep getting error messages, can anyone help? Code below:

```
QGIS version: 3.8.3-Zanzibar
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 2.4.2
GEOS version: 3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.2 b55d2125
PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Contour' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BAND' : 1, 'CREATE_3D' : False, 'FIELD_NAME' : 'ELEV', 'IGNORE_NODATA' : False, 'INPUT' : '/Users/Mim/Desktop/OS203/CW2/Bathymetric Survey Coursework-20200327/Final Bathymetry GeoTiff/PlymouthSound_1m_final.tif', 'INTERVAL' : 10, 'NODATA' : None, 'OFFSET' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

GDAL command:
gdal_contour -b 1 -a ELEV -i 10.0 -f "ESRI Shapefile" "/Users/Mim/Desktop/OS203/CW2/Bathymetric Survey Coursework-20200327/Final Bathymetry GeoTiff/PlymouthSound_1m_final.tif" /var/folders/81/njbhr3dn3556brkh725_7_fm0000gn/T/processing_1b3ff932a52446e38b6da3b9147e595c/ec4a71fdc1d44220b082c3a61362c3b1/OUTPUT.shp
GDAL command output:
/bin/sh: gdal_contour: command not found

Execution completed in 0.10 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/var/folders/81/njbhr3dn3556brkh725_7_fm0000gn/T/processing_1b3ff932a52446e38b6da3b9147e595c/ec4a71fdc1d44220b082c3a61362c3b1/OUTPUT.shp'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>/var/folders/81/njbhr3dn3556brkh725_7_fm0000gn/T/processing_1b3ff932a52446e38b6da3b9147e595c/ec4a71fdc1d44220b082c3a61362c3b1/OUTPUT.shp</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Comment: Do you have gdal installed? "/bin/sh: gdal_contour: command not found" - how did you install qgis?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.